# Mono for Android: Emulator Disk Size

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

When I create an emulator for Mono for Android, it is too small to get the run times installed for the new Mono for Android 4.2.

How can I create a big enough emulator to support it using the AVD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the system/data partition size, you can use the `-partition-size` option of the emulator. To start a 512MB sized emulator, use:

`emulator -partition-size 512 -avd <your-avd-name>`

`eg: emulator -partition-size 512 -avd MonoForAndroid_API_14_2 -no-snapshot-load`

You can alter the SD card size of the AVD from the AVD Manager. From AVD manager, select your AVD -> Edit -> SD card -> Size (Enter new size)